# Send Email to person on build failure on his commits

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to Send Email specific to a person who's changes caused build failure.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked up at [email-ext](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/) plugin?

At post you can set up the trigger failure:

```
post {
   failure {
       emailext body: "$env.BODY_CONTENT",
                mimeType: 'text/html',
                recipientProviders: [requestor(), developers(), culprits()]
                subject: '$DEFAULT_SUBJECT',
                to: env.PROJECT_RECIPIENTS
   }
}
```

Make sure to configure email-ext plugin.
recipientProviders will add destinations based on:

- requestor: the person who started the build
- developers: to every person who commit to the repo
- culprits: to every person who commit since last non-broken build

You can remove developers and requestor, culprits is the option you're looking for. You can also remove to: